# How do I configure basic LAN to WAN on a Cisco 1921 router?

Tags: networking, router, routing

I am trying to configure a Cisco 1921 and wanted to double check my configuration logic.

The configuration is very straightforward as everything but basic routing will be managed by my SonicWALL appliance.

**Desired Configuration**

- GigabitEthernet 0/0 is WAN interface (direct to fibre provider)
- GigabitEthernet 0/1 should connect to my firewall

Any advice as to what I'm doing wrong below would be appreciated, with my main questions being:

- Do I need to configure GigbitEthernet 0/1 (LAN) with the same local address details configured on my SonicWALL?
- Where do I specify default gateway? In the route or via ip default-gateway?

**Current Configuration**

```
gla-rtr-01#sh run
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 4235 bytes
!
! Last configuration change at 22:32:01 UTC Sat May 13 2017
!
version 15.4
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname gla-rtr-01
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
logging buffered 51200 warnings
!
no aaa new-model
!
no ip domain lookup
ip domain name yourdomain.com
ip cef
no ipv6 cef
!
redundancy

interface Embedded-Service-Engine0/0
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 description External
 ip address 88.XXX.XXX.XXX 255.255.255.248
 duplex full
 speed auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
ip forward-protocol nd
!
ip http server
ip http access-class 23
ip http authentication local
ip http secure-server
ip http timeout-policy idle 60 life 86400 requests 10000
!
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 88.XXX.XXX.XXX <-- GATEWAY
!
access-list 23 permit any
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Any advice as to what I'm doing wrong below would be appreciated...*

Entire books exist to address this very topic of *Best Practices*.  When a Cisco router is at the Internet edge of your network it is generally recommended to configure a [Cisco IOS Firewall Zone-Based Policy](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/security/ios-firewall/index.html).  Remote access via SSH should also be extremely limited.  The list however, goes on.

> *Do I need to configure GigbitEthernet 0/1 (LAN) with the same local address details configured on my SonicWALL?*

Both interfaces must be in the same subnet.

> *Where do I specify default gateway? In the route or via ip default-gateway?*

In your use-case, the `ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 88.XXX.XXX.XXX` command is the most appropriate.  This command sets the **Default Route**.  This [Cisco Technote](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/routing-information-protocol-rip/16448-default.html) describes in great detail the differences between three commonly confused commands: `ip default-gateway`, `ip default-network`, and `ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0`.

In reference to the `ip default-gateway` command:

> "The ip default-gateway command differs from the other two commands. It should only be used when ip routing is disabled on the Cisco router."

This command is more often used in Cisco switches when in L2 operation.

Answer (score 0):

> any advice:

For me, I will connect my firewall to ISP, Then Cisco will be my LAN. I will route traffic through Cisco because it's his job.